# Unhandeld WPF 4.0 CP Exception

Tags: wpf, exception, .net-4.0

A customer of mine has the following strange exception.

The problem is, that I can't reproduce it on any of my machines.
Everywhere it runs fine, even on a fresh Win 7 64bit installation.

```
Problemsignatur:

  Problemereignisname:                       CLR20r3
  Problemsignatur 01:                          mysoftware.exe
  Problemsignatur 02:                          2.20.000.0
  Problemsignatur 03:                          4e5d24bc
  Problemsignatur 04:                          PresentationFramework
  Problemsignatur 05:                          4.0.0.0
  Problemsignatur 06:                          4d930fa2
  Problemsignatur 07:                          a34
  Problemsignatur 08:                          46
  Problemsignatur 09:                          System.IO.IOException
  Betriebsystemversion:                        6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Gebietsschema-ID:                             1031
  Zusatzinformation 1:                          0a9e
  Zusatzinformation 2:                          0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Zusatzinformation 3:                          0a9e
  Zusatzinformation 4:                          0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

**EDIT:**

The error message is strange, because it tells:

```
Exception:
System.IO.IOException: Die Ressource "app.xaml" kann nicht gefunden werden.
   bei MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   bei System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   bei System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream()
   bei System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   bei xxx.App.InitializeComponent()
   bei xxx.App.Main()
```

Which is really strange, because at the most other PCs, the App has no problem to show up.

Could someone point my to the right direction please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: A stack-trace, inner exceptions & respective exception messages would be quite helpful, so if you currently are not logging that it might be a good idea to implement that.

Comment: "Even on a fresh..."  --- Often testing isn't about having a fresh system, but a dirty, long-running, or unpredictable one.  There are software toolkits for gathering information about the platform and running environment of an application, though I haven't investigated them in detail.  Maybe you can find one and have your customer run it, then send you the data?  (For all we know, they have bad memory, are running out of memory, have a corrupted dll or exe, or one of a thousand other issues that makes your product look bad that are only partially in your product's area of responsibility).

Comment: I added a DispatcherUnhandledException handler, but it doesn't seem to go in there. Is there an other way to add an event handler for unhandled Exceptions?

Comment: That will only help if the exception occurs on the main UI thread. Try adding an AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException handler. It won't stop the process from dying but at least you can gather info.

Comment: Even with an AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException handler, I can not catch the exception. I really run out of ideas ...

Comment: Ah maybe I found something, will try it tomorrow. But I added the handler in the OnStartup method that I have overriden. I will try to add the handler in the App Constructor ...

Answer (score 0):

As it says something about an IOException it might be that the customer or customer's system has been using a file that the application would have liked to modify or something similar.

Comment: Could be. But it would be really great, if I could see the real exception. Adding a DispatcherUnhandledException handler seems not work correctly. Is there an other way to get these unhandled exceptions?

Comment: Try what Jeff said in the comment on the question, that is what i would have suggested as well. (You will need to typecheck & cast the `e.ExceptionObject`, no idea why that is not typed as exception.)

Comment: Yep, currently packaged a testversion. I will try that tomorrow at the customers PC. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar exception. It would occur when a particular WPF window would load for the first time.

After a lot of digging, I found the cause of the exception was that the WPF window was using a 3rd party UI control that referenced a few unmanaged dll files, and the unmanaged dll files were not present on the user’s PC.

Answer (score 0):

Might have to do with permissions for that particular user. Does the error occur for all users on the same machine?

We had a strange WPF problem once which was due to old graphical driver versions on that machine. Even got a BSoD a couple of times.

Comment: Thx. I will try to check that.